# add php code to display sku in before error message

Tags: php, magento

we are using an extension to import the products.

This is the code we are using to display some error message.

we are using this file to display error message : http://pastebin.com/uvwaC6a7

```
$errors[] = Mage::helper('mpmassuploadaddons')->__('Skip import row, attribute "%s" does not exist', $attributeCode);
```

Before the error message , i want to display the sku . i guesss usually we need to display following code to display sku :

```
$sku = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSku();
```

i want to merge the above 2 lines of code, so that i want to display as

"sku : some error message"....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$errors[] = Mage::helper('mpmassuploadaddons')->__('Skip import row, attribute "%s" does not exist and SKu is "%s"', $attributeCode,$sku);
```

Comment: hi, it did't worked for me , please help me for this question : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86405/display-sku-infront-of-error-message